# JS call a different method on array depending on boolean

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I have array `var A = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];`. If Boolean `callFilter` is true, I want to call `.filter(x => x ==='bb')` on it, if its false I want to call `.concat('dd')`.
Is there a way other than

```
var result;
if(callFilter){
    result = A.filter(x=> x === 'bb');
} else {
    result = A.concat('dd');
}
console.log(result) // ['bb']
```

Id like to use ternary operation, but dont know if its possible to use it in form of

```
result = A[(callFilter) ? .filter(x => x === 'bb') : .concat('dd)]; // this doesnt work.
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `result = callFilter ? A.filter(x=> x === 'bb') : A.concat('dd')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. You can access a property conditionally, though that would require writing the condition twice in this case:

```js
let result = A[callFilter ? 'filter' : 'concat'](callFilter ? x => x === 'bb' : 'dd');
```

It is better to just move the condition and repeat the variable `A` twice.

```js
let result = callFilter ? A.filter(x => x === 'bb') : A.concat('dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator like this:

```js
const A = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
const callFilter = true;

const result = callFilter ? A.filter(x => x === 'bb') : A.concat('dd');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let result = callFilter ? A.filter(x => x === "bb"): A.concat("dd");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This appears identical to the two earlier answers; can you expand on how this code-only answer is an improvement?